# Unexpected EOF when using golang bufio in gzip

Tags: go, gzip, bufferedreader

Golang Code Here: (include 4 files here)
https://gist.github.com/kmahyyg/02a2da2970001de455f847f4e7525aff

When defined as above, compress a **big** file (512M here, a bin created by `dd` from `/dev/urandom`).

If you use `SetWriter(out)`, try to pass `out` as a `bufio.Writer` but keep the struct field definition as `io.Writer`, and the same as Reader part.

Then try decompress, you will get an unexpected EOF error.

But if you pass `out` as a `io.Writer`, everything will be fine.

Compress function have no errors.

Why use `bufio.Writer` will cause unexpected EOF?

Note:

- after some observation, it seems that file smaller than a specific size (here, is 337MB on my machine) will not get unexpected EOF.
- The official `gunzip` extract the same gzip file which caused `unexpected EOF` will only get about the first 337M part of data, then get the "corrupted file" message.

Edit: 1. Full code attached.
2. Screen shot here: (Use zstd as an example, same result when use gzip)

[image: Use zstd as an example, same result when use gzip]

Comment: I think we need more details to be clear, but my educated guess is that you didn't `Flush` the `bufio.Writer`.

Comment: @leafbebop: I thought it too, but isn't there a buffer limitation, to flush every _n_ operations?

Comment: @Inian Unless you are streaming, most likely you only need to `Flush` at the end, before closing the underlying `io.Writer`.

Comment: I edited the question to attach the full code.

Comment: @PotatoChips I suggest changing `var outWriter io.Writer = bufio.NewWriter(outFile)` to  `outWriter := bufio.NewWriter(outFile)`, and then adding `defer outWriter.Flush()` immediately after that line. Unfortunately this whole program is too complicated for me to test on mobile so I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for @leafbebop, I flush it manually, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

@leafbebop has the correct answer. The `io.Writer` will not automatically flush the buffer when close. So you must manually flush it before close when use `bufio.Writer` as `io.Writer`